# synchronization for audio and video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

Here i need to created the video from number of images but i also include a audio also i also included the Airplaycode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to create a animated images(series of images) do one thing play audio in background or on button click and for animated images try this:-

```
animationView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(157,354, 45, 100)] ;
animationView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.jpg"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"image7.jpg"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image5.jpg"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"image6.jpg"], nil];

animationView.animationDuration = .65;
animationView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animationView startAnimating];
[self.view addSubview:animationView];
[animationView release];
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir,but i need to convert  as whole video format and upload to facebook and twitter as a whole package sir. so that i use AVAsset to combine the audio and video ,from that i sucessfully created the video from the series of images but i need to combine the audio also sir i reffered the sample code as AIRplay code from apple thank u sir